# Every $p$-norm ($p \in [0,\infty]$) generates the same class of open sets on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

The following claim has been made in my multivariable analysis class, and I think I have the idea of the proof but I can't quite seem to get down to the rigorous proof the instructor wants:

Every $p$-norm ($p \in [0,\infty]$) generates the same class of open sets on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I'll also give the definitions of the terms my instructor is using:

Let $B(X,r) = \{ Y \in \mathbb{R}^n \text{ such that } ||Y-X||<r\}$ where $|| \bullet ||$ is the standard Euclidean norm. Then a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open iff for all $X\in A$, there exists $r>0$ such that $B(X,r)\subseteq A$.

So my idea is that since all the $p$-norms are equivalent, and if there is a ball of radius $r$ in the $2$-norm, we should be able to find a ball in any $p$-norm that contains it and remains inside of $A$, but I can't quite see how we can do that.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of proving that norms give the same topology is to find inequalities

$$c||x||_1\leq ||x||_2\leq C||x||_1\ \ \ \ \text{ with }c>0.$$

$$\text{If }\ \ q>p\geq1\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{ then }\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{n^{1/q}}{n^{1/p}}||x||_p\leq||x||_q\leq||x||_p.$$

The first inequality is the [generalized mean inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) and the second is because

$$\frac{||x||_p}{||x||_q}=\underbrace{\left|\left|\frac{1}{||x||_q}x\right|\right|_p\geq\left(\sum_i\frac{|x_i|^q}{||x||_q^q}\right)^{1/p}}_{q>p\implies a^q\leq a^p\text{ for }|a|<1.}=1^{1/p}=1\ \ \ \ \text{ because }\ \ \ \ \frac{|x_i|}{||x||_q}\leq1.$$

Now, such a pair of inequalities allows you to, for every open ball in one norm to put an open ball from the other norm inside. Suppose $B_p(a,r)$ is a ball of radius $r$ in the $p$-norm, then $$B_p(a,\frac{n^{1/p}}{n^{1/q}}r)\supset B_q(a,r)\supset B_p(a,r).$$

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Wait, should you flip the fraction in the second inequality? Wouldn't we want $\dfrac{||X||_q}{||X||_p} \le 1$?

Comment: It should be fixed now. $p$ and $q$ look too much alike.

Comment: And one more thing; why exactly are we assured that $\dfrac{x_i}{||x||_q}\le 1$?

Comment: Because $||x||_q=(|x_i|^q+\text{ some non-negative stuff })^{1/q}\geq (|x_i|+0)^{1/q}=|x_i|$.

Comment: Ah, of course. But it looks like you mean $(|x_i|^q+0)^{1/q}$ in that second to last bit there. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @walkar Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

For $0<p<1$ the $p$-norm is only a quasinorm. Nevertheless, it is not hard to check that all of them give the same topology as the $\infty$-norm

$$||(x_1, \ldots, x_n)||_{\infty} = \max|x_i|$$

Let $x$ with $||x||_{\infty} < \epsilon$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p \le n \epsilon^p$ and so $||x||_{p} < n^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot \epsilon$. Therefore

$$B_{\infty}( \epsilon) \subset B_{p}( n^{\frac{1}{p}}\epsilon) $$
(balls with same center) and because of degree $1$ positive homogeneity of the (quasi-)norms we get
$$B_{\infty}( n^{-\frac{1}{p}}\epsilon) \subset B_{p}( \epsilon) $$

On the other hand

$$||x||_p = (\sum|x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}\ge (\max|x_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}= \max |x_i| = ||x||$$
 Therefore, if $||x||_p < \epsilon $ then $||x||_{\infty} < \epsilon$, and we get
$$  B_{p}( \epsilon) \subset B_{\infty}( \epsilon)$$

Therefore 
$$B_{\infty}( n^{-\frac{1}{p}}\epsilon) \subset B_{p}( \epsilon) \subset B_{\infty}( \epsilon)$$

and so $||\cdot ||_p$, $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ give the same topology.

Comment: Hard to improve on the solution of @Pp.. : especially since the constants he provides are the optimal ones. This solution takes an easier road of comparing $||\cdot ||_p$ with $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ only.